# Mismatching Versions - How Can I Tell When a Server is Going to be Upgraded

Tags: force.com, appexchange

I have a managed packaged which I successfully uploaded in NA7 server which was upgraded to winter 2015 release.

Now I try to install it on EU3 server (of one of my clients) which still did not get this upgrade, how can I know when EU3 server will get this upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This link](https://trust.salesforce.com/trust/maintenance/) will help I think, they always announce release schedule

Answer (score 2):

Please check out this link for salesforce maintainance schedule:
[Salesforce maintenance schedule](https://trust.salesforce.com/trust/maintenance/)